# How to make A request on two tables with core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I ve got 2 tables link by a 1-to many relationship, how could I retrieve data using NSFetchRequest from both tables using simply one request ?
Something like in SQL "select * from Table1 Table2 Where id.table1 =id.table2"?
Or perhaps I miss something with coredata ! Can I reach objects simply through relationship ?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pick your objects from table1, and access their relationship property, that will fetch the related objects from table2.

If you want to learn more about Core Data, Marcus Zarra has done a book and also a course on iDeveloperTv. book is cheaper, both are fantastic.

Comment: thanks, i knew i forget something!Thanks for ressources as well